# VSTS performance as WIT count grows?

Tags: azure-devops

We're about to switch from Fogbugz to VSTS and would like to import all of our existing Fogbugz work items, which numbers about 17000.

Would a volume of work items in this range affect the overall performance of VSTS?

Comment: The work item records are stored in a SQL Azure database that we can’t access it directly, too much data must affect performance, because it takes more time to retrieve data from SQL database, but the performance won’t be decline too much. On the other hand, this blog is related to data limit that you may want to know https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2013/11/20/how-much-data-can-you-put-on-vsonline/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, VSTS is running bigger numbers without fuss.

That said, you can have performance issues if you do not organize your data along some built-in dimension. Imagine the UI grinding to a halt because it is trying to display all 17,000 items at once.

If you map your original data to Iterations (i.e. Sprints), Areas, Projects, Teams and so on, I see no issue at all.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the previous answer, you can also test that for yourself:

Open a (free) test VSTS Account and use their REST API to input either your 17000 items or 17000 fake item (random data) and then check for yourself if the UI is still responsive.

You can also contact a MS Program Manager that work on VSTS and ask him.

To my knowledge, MS uses VSTS for all their products which must be bigger than 17000 Work Items

Comment: Those were my thoughts exactly. Testing is on the agenda for this week. Just wanted to get some insight from others to catch some real-world scenarios.